# How to know if this tor browser downloaded is not fake?

Tags: configuration, bridge

I have downloaded tor but it is acting a bit funny ,
I used to configure bridges or tails , but after I signed in I have no access to configure as I live where  ISP is doing deep inspection and everything is censored. 
2- I am not sure if I am using fake tor browser.
I appreciate any kind of help 
Baback

Comment: https://support.torproject.org/tbb/how-to-verify-signature/

Answer (score 0):

This can be done quite easily under normal circumstances. You will have to verify the signature and the sha256sum. A detailed description how to do this can be found [here](https://2019.www.torproject.org/docs/verifying-signatures.html.en) on the official Tor project page.

But since you mentioned that your ISP is monitoring you, you should be aware of the fact that merely opening the Tor project webpage may cause some alert. You didn't mention where you downloaded Tor. If it wasn't from the official page and you need to avoid all officially Tor-related sites, it might get difficult to actually verify it.